# Question based on chords of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

**Question:**

Given a circle and two points $P$ and $Q$ not neccessarily on that circle. Perpendiculars are drawn from points $P$ and $Q$ to the [polar lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar) of the points $Q$ and $P$ respectively. Prove that the ratio of of lengths of those perpendiculars are equal to the ratio of distances of point $P$ and $Q$ from the centre of circle.

[image: Illustration]

**Attempt:**

I solved this question by assuming the circle equation as $x^2+y^2=1$

Let $P$ be $(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q$ be $(x_2,y_2)$.

Polar of $P$ is $$xx_1+yy_1-1=0$$
Polar of $Q$ is $$xx_2+yy_2-1=0$$

The perpendicular distance from $P$ to polar of $Q$ is $$\frac{x_1x_2+y_1y_2-1}{\sqrt{{x_2}^2+{y_2}^2}}$$
Similarly, perpendicular distance from $Q$ is $$\frac{x_1x_2+y_1y_2-1}{\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{y_1}^2}}$$
Ratio is $$\frac{\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{y_1}^2}}{\sqrt{{x_2}^2+{y_2}^2}}$$which is the ratio of distance from centre of circle $(0,0)$ to the points $P$ and $Q$.

> Is there any method to solve this using **geometry**? It looks like a problem involving two similar triangles.

Comment: So P and Q are any two points in the plane?

Comment: Yes. From P, two tangents are drawn and then a line joining the point of contacts of tangents with the circle is drawn. (Chord of contact).

Comment: Is there any way of using basic concepts of geometry in this problem? I am not satisfied with my method. (This problem became easy only because I assumed the circle to be centered at origin).

Comment: Without loss of generosity, we can have that assumed.

Comment: So this is the only way of solving the problem?

Comment: @AdityaDev: Hope you don't mind my edit, in particular the fact that I renamed your [chord of contact](http://spssmaths.tripod.com/cg_cir_2.htm) to [polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar). I was confused for a while because to me a chord is just a line segment, while you compute the distance to the infinite extension of that segment, which is the polar. Hope you like the image.

Comment: The diagram is perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was staring at this$ \space\downarrow$

[image]

for nearly a week, and couldn't come up with anything 'elegant' because I was searching for similar triangles. Then I drank a few cups of coffee and remembered something:

> $\square AGIO\sim \square BHJO$ . Quadrilaterals can be similar too.